# <input type="time" /> value doesn't insert in mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-insert

I want to insert  value in a database and it inserted empty. I want help for this necessary. 
This is the variable of time :

```
$rm_time = $_POST['rm-time'];
```

**PHP**

```
    if(empty($_POST['rm-name']) or empty($_POST['rm-details'])){
            ?>
            <h3 style="margin-top: 30px;text-align: center;font-size: 25px;color: red;" dir="rtl">Error</h3>
            <?php
        }else{
            $rm_name = $_POST['rm-name'];
            $rm_details = $_POST['rm-details'];
            $rm_date = $_POST['rm-date'];
            $rm_time = $_POST['rm-time'];
            $rm_insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO reminders (r_name, r_details, r_date, r_time) VALUES ('$rm_name', '$rm_details', '$rm_date', '$rm_time')");
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="reminder.php?rm=make" method="post">
        <table class="rm" width="auto" border="0px">
            <tr>
                <td class="rm-form-text">Reminder date/time :</td>
                <td><input autofocus="" name="rm-date" type="date" id="rm" /> / <input name"rm-time" type="time" id="rm" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rm-form-text">Remimnder name :</td>
                <td><input name="rm-name" type="text" id="rm" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rm-form-text">Reminder details :</td>
                <td><textarea dir="rtl" name="rm-details" id="rm-ta"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="save-reminder" type="submit" class="sp-submit" value="Save!" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?
    exit;
```

Comment: What format is rm-time in, and what format is the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

FROM :  `<input name"rm-time" type="time" id="rm" /></td>`

TO :    `<input name="rm-time" type="time" id="rm" /></td>`

Answer (score 1):

here your syntax is wrong.

Use

```
<input name= "rm-time" type="time" id="rm" />
```

instead of

```
<input name"rm-time" type="time" id="rm" />
```